# Facebook like button doesn't work in certain browsers or on certain OS

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

So, I use the same **fb-like plugin** (fbml based one) code on 5 different pages on the website. The only difference is the different data in meta description and type of content. All pages were checked through the fb linter and it says everything is okay. All the buttons work alright in Chrome under Mac OS, but in Firefox, Opera (Mac & PC) and Chrome on PC (Windows) 3 of these buttons do not appear and none of them work in Safari on Mac. I can see that fb scripts are working some way, you can see the code with built-in developer tools in Opera or Chrome, and the element does occupy the space, but the button is not shown...

*I've tested* all the code in the pages including html, js and css line by line and it looks like it doesn't affect the fb-likes. I've also take the code from the page with the problem fb-like and make the new page with the only difference in fb-like href property - and it works. But when I change the href to the address of the page where like button didn't work - it stops working. So as I understand the problem is not on the website side, but since the fb-linter doesn't show any errors the problem is not on fb side either. But where is it then?

I've contacted the fb developers team, but I guess it may take them extremely long to answer , so I'd like to know if sombody had such a problem before. Any opinions or thoughts are appreciated!
[Here's](http://lisashahno.com/) the website.

Thanks in advance everybody(:

~

Comment: The same issue on fb developers bug tracker: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17365